# PHP append a key => value pair to an array

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm using a foreach cycle like this:

```
foreach($cats_arr as $category) {
    $options_arr[$category->name] = false;
}
```

and when I var_dump($options_arr['Articles']) it comes out like this, so I assume that I'm building the array properly:

```
bool(false) string(1) "5"
```

Next, I need to assign that array as a value of a key-value pair in another array, and then it breaks. I'm doing it like this:

```
$admin_options = array(
"cats" => $options_arr
);
```

So I can access the array with $admin_options['cats'], but how to I access the array's keys that's assigned to the "cats" key?

EDIT: Here's what comes out when I var_dump($admin_options['cats'])

`array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["Articles"]=> bool(false) ["Blog Posts"]=> bool(false) ["News"]=> bool(false) ["Uncategorized"]=> bool(false) } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $options_arr contains multiple keys, so you will have to either specify the key or use a foreach loop:

```
// Echo first key
echo $admin_options['cats'][0]['Articles'];

// Or this for all the keys
foreach($admin_options['cats'] as $cat) {
    echo $cat['Articles'];
}
```